Get largest cumulative sum for row subtypes without using a self join
I'm working on a problem and am stuck at making it work without a join.
I've got a table, where each product_type has a number of regions. I need to find the region with the maximum quantity sold for each product_type.
I can do it using one self join but have to do it without a join:
Select region, max(sold_sum) from
(Select distinct region, geo, sum(quat) over (partition by region,geo) as sold_sum 
from tab1 order by 1) t1
group by region

Here's the input table and expected output:
Sales Data



product_type
geography
quantity_sold




1
E
56


1
N
34


1
W
56


1
W
34


2
N
76


2
N
98


2
W
45


2
W
21


3
N
67


3
S
76


3
W
98


4
E
43


4
S
82


4
S
43


5
E
21


5
S
34



Expected Output



product_type
geography
total_sold




1
W
90


2
N
174


3
W
98


4
S
125


5
S
34



(Original image with the table data)

Please don't use images - use table markdown

Try below query
WITH SalesData AS (
    SELECT
        product_type,
        geography,
        SUM(quantity_sold) AS total_sold
    FROM product_sales
    GROUP BY product_type, geography
),
RankedSales AS (
    SELECT
        product_type,
        geography,
        total_sold,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_type ORDER BY total_sold DESC) AS rn
    FROM SalesData
)
SELECT
    product_type,
    geography,
    total_sold
FROM RankedSales
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY product_type;

db-fiddle

Its almost same as using a join, can we do just by using analytical functions

A good answer includes an explanation

You can get the desired result by using analytical functions like RANK instead of self join like below :

ranked_sales CTE calculates the total quantity sold for each combination of product_type and geography as part of SUM(quantity_sold)
This CTE then divides the data into partitions based on product_type and orders the data based on total quantity sold in descending order. The highest total quantity sold gets rank 1.

Fiddle for Oracle 11g
WITH ranked_sales AS (
    SELECT 
        product_type, 
        geography, 
        SUM(quantity_sold) AS total_sold,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product_type ORDER BY SUM(quantity_sold) DESC) AS rnk
    FROM 
        product_sales
    GROUP BY 
        product_type, 
        geography
)
SELECT 
    product_type, 
    geography, 
    total_sold
FROM 
    ranked_sales
WHERE 
    rnk = 1
ORDER BY 
    product_type;

Output



PRODUCT_TYPE
GEOGRAPHY
TOTAL_SOLD




1
W
90


2
N
174


3
W
98


4
S
125


5
S
34




Here is one of the options using cte aggregation and Row_Number() Over() analytic function:
WITH 
  totals AS
    ( SELECT s.*, Row_Number() Over(Partition By s.product_type Order By TOTAL Desc) "RN"
      FROM  ( Select      product_type, geography, Sum(quantity_sold) "TOTAL"
              From        product_sales
              Group By    product_type, geography
            ) s
   ) 
Select     product_type, geography, TOTAL
From       totals
Where      RN = 1
Order By   product_type, geography

R e s u l t :



PRODUCT_TYPE
GEOGRAPHY
TOTAL




1
W
90


2
N
174


3
W
98


4
S
125


5
S
34



fiddle
